# Lightning Videos

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community

Is it possible to display external videos in lightning component using iframe container?

I have got cross-frame error if i try with iframe tag.Is there any way to display videos in lightning component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Something like this should work. I was able to do with youtube video.

```
    <iframe width="640" height="415" src="{!v.youtubeid}"> </iframe>
```

Pass the video id in "src" attribute and you should be able to access it.

Please [check](http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/06/06/play-youtube-video-lightning-component/) this blog for more details.

Comment: Now it displays the video, but player option is disabled. I am not able to click on it. Any idea on this?

Comment: Can you check the documentation of iframe. and verify the controls.